# Why can't I load the VisualForce Chart data for a different year through Javascript?

Tags: apex, charts, custom-controller, visualforce-charting, remote-action

Currently looking at [Refreshing Chart Data Using JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_refreshing_data_javascript_remoting.htm)

After changing `hidden="true"` to `hidden="false"`, the pie chart displays when the page initially loads, however when I change the year, nothing happens (I don't even get any expected error messages).

This is my VisualForce Page

```
<!-- see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_refreshing_data_javascript_remoting.htm -->
<apex:page controller="VF_PieChartVFCtrl">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jquery}"/>
    <script>
        retrieveChartData = function (callback) 
        {
           var year = $("#theYear").val();

           var retrieveCallback = function(result, event) 
           {
               if(event.status && result && (result.constructor === Array)) 
               {
                   callback(result);
                   RemotingPieChart.show();
               }
               else 
               {
                   $("#remoteResponseErrors").text(event.message + ((event.type === 'exception')  ?  ('<br/>' + event.where) : ''));
               }                   
           };

           Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction ( '{!$RemoteAction.VF_PieChartVFCtrl.getRemotePieData}', year, retrieveCallback , { escape: true } );
        };    
    </script>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.VF_JavaScriptRefreshingPieChartJS}"/>


    <apex:pageBlock title="Charts">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Visualforce Charting + JavaScript Remoting">

            <apex:chart height="350" width="450" data="retrieveChartData" name="RemotingPieChart" hidden="false">
                <apex:pieSeries dataField="data" labelField="name"/>
                <apex:legend position="right"/>
            </apex:chart>

            <div>
                <select id="theYear" onChange="vfStudy.refreshRemoteChart();">
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                    <option value="2012">2012</option>
                    <option value="2011">2011</option>
                    <option value="2010">2010</option>
                </select>
                <span id="statusDisplay"></span>
                <span id="remoteResponseErrors"></span>
            </div>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

This is the script $Resource.VF_JavaScriptRefreshingPieChartJS

```
var vfStudy = vfStudy  || {};

vfStudy.refreshRemoteChart = function() 
{
    $("#statusDisplay").text("Loading...");
    retrieveChartData
    (
        function(statusElement)
        {
            return function(data)
            {
                RemotingPieChart.reload(data);
                $("#statusDisplay").text("");
            };
        }
        (statusElement)
    );
};
```

And this is my VF Controller:

```
 public class VF_PieChartVFCtrl  
{
    private final String BASE_URL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
    public String getBaseURL() { return BASE_URL; }

    private final List<VF_PieWedgeData> PIE_WEDGE_DATA_2013_LIST = new List<VF_PieWedgeData>
    {
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Jan', 30),    // These numbers are absolute quantities, not percentages 
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Feb', 15),    // The chart component will calculate the percentages.
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Mar', 10),
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Apr', 20),
        new VF_PieWedgeData('May', 20), 
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Jun', 05)
    };

    private final List<VF_PieWedgeData> PIE_WEDGE_DATA_OTHER_LIST= new List<VF_PieWedgeData>
    {
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Jan', 20), 
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Feb', 35),
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Mar', 30),
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Apr', 40),
        new VF_PieWedgeData('May', 05), 
        new VF_PieWedgeData('Jun', 10)
    };

    private final static String DEFAULT_YEAR = '2013'; 

    public String chartYear
    {
        get
        {
            if (chartYear == null) { chartYear = DEFAULT_YEAR; }

            return chartYear;
        }
        set;
    }

    // Years available to be charted, for <apex:selectList>
    public static List<SelectOption> getChartYearOptions()
    {
        return new List<SelectOption> 
        {
            new SelectOption('2013','2013'),
            new SelectOption('2012','2012'),
            new SelectOption('2011','2011'),
            new SelectOption('2010','2010')
        };
    }

    @RemoteAction public static List<VF_PieWedgeData> getRemotePieData(String year)
    {
        if (year == null) { year = DEFAULT_YEAR; }
        VF_PieChartVFCtrl controller = new VF_PieChartVFCtrl();
                   return controller.generatePieData(year);
    }

    public List<VF_PieWedgeData> getPieData() 
    {
        return generatePieData(this.chartYear);
    }

    // Private data "generator"
    private List<VF_PieWedgeData> generatePieData(String yearAsString)
    {
        return (yearAsString.equals('2013'))
                ? PIE_WEDGE_DATA_2013_LIST
                : PIE_WEDGE_DATA_OTHER_LIST;
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong that the chart does not update as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

JavaScript references to "RemotingPieChart" needed to include to include the organization's namespace (e.g. "Sledgehammer.RemotingPieChart")