# Can I move this JavaScript function which VisualForce used out of the global namespace?

Tags: javascript, bestpractice, javascript-remoting, visualforce-charting, namespace

Currently looking at [Refreshing Chart Data Using JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_refreshing_data_javascript_remoting.htm)

Reading about JavaScript best practices, I came across the idea of keeping functions out of the global namespace, so I tried to refactor the Javascript to look like this:

```
   var vfStudy = vfStudy  || {};

vfStudy.refreshRemoteChart = function() 
{
    $("#statusDisplay").text("Loading...");
    retrieveChartData
    (
        function(statusElement)
        {
            return function(data)
            {
                RemotingPieChart.reload(data);
                $("#statusDisplay").text("");
            };
        }
        (statusElement)
    );
};

vfStudy.retrieveChartData = function (callback) 
{
   var year = $("#theYear").val();

   var retrieveCallback = function(result, event) 
   {
       if(event.status && result && (result.constructor === Array)) 
       {
           callback(result);
           RemotingPieChart.show();
       }
       else 
       {
           $("#remoteResponseErrors").text(event.message + ((event.type === 'exception')  ?  ('<br/>' + event.where) : ''));
       }                   
   };

   Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction ( 'Sledgehammer.VF_PieChartVFCtrl.getRemotePieData', year, retrieveCallback , { escape: true } );
};
```

Moving the `refreshRemoteChart` into the vfStudy namespace worked as expect, but even updating `data="retrieveChartData"` to `data="vfStudy.retrieveChartData"`, the VisualForce Chart would not render.

Is it possible for me to move this function out of the global namespace?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian, I think you can address this problem by adding the following steps to your approach:

1. Before you define your namespace, create a dummy variable: `var noData = new Object();`
2. When defining the component, specify `data="noData"`. This is simply to avoid JavaScript runtime errors. As you would expect, no data will be bound to the chart.
3. At the end of the page, add another `script` element and simply call your `vfStudy.refreshRemoteChart()` function

I tried this out in my DE org and was able to get it to work (I think) the way you want. You do need a few extra lines of code, but you'll end up with a clean global namespace. Please take a look at this gist for reference: https://gist.github.com/martyychang/2162c3f467927f7b3601

Comment: Cheers for this!  Will try it out on Monday when I'm back at the office.  :-)

Comment: Tried it, but it does not work.  Problem may be related to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56833/why-cant-i-load-the-visualforce-chart-data-for-a-different-year-through-javascr  ... but even going with code direct from the tutorial instead of my own, this still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @BrianKessler. I wonder why the code works for me but not for you. What is the behavior you're seeing? Here's a walkthrough of what it looks like in my DE org: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAZdCgMWbdk

Comment: There isn't much behavior to see.  The page renders, minus the chart.  The word "loading..." displays, as if I changed the year.  But then nothing happens; neither a chart is rendered nor the "loading..." text disappears.

Comment: I was looking at your code in git and I noticed that you've prefixed "RemotingPieChart" with "myc" (e.g. "myc.RemotingPieChart"), which wasn't in either the original tutorial or my code.  Where is that coming from?  As-is, it doesn't seem to help me... but maybe I need some other prefix?

Comment: Figured out that "myc" seems to be your namespace.  When I added my namespace ("Sledgehammer") in its place, everything started working!

Comment: Ah, yes. The namespace is a trick (and I haven't figured out how best to address that when posting gists) that I discovered as I was trying to figure out why _my_ code wasn't working after I copied and pasted the tutorial code. Luckily the [apex:chart](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chart.htm) documentation explained its use.